# PSF WiFi module - Is it similar to ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

Some products (as TUYA and SONOFF) are using a PSF wifi module. In this [link](https://itead.cc/diy-kits-guides/psf-b04-application-guide/), PSF-B04 is reffers as ESP8285 design.

does anyone flash a sketch to such chip ? should it be reffered as ESP8285 when selecting chip type in Arduino IDE ?

Guy

Comment: This is actually an [ESP8285](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8285_datasheet_en.pdf) (not 8265) design, which is a version of the ESP8266 with integrated 1MB or 2MB Flash memory. From a programming perspective, aside from the memory size, it's identical to the ESP8266. The ESP8266 Arduino Core also supports this chip.

Comment: @StarCat That was a typo, thank you. So chip wise, I can upload sketch as any other esp8266 (without any change is MCU type at Arduino IDE ) ?

Comment: Did you look in the boards menu for the esp8266 support package?

Comment: @timemage what do you mean? I saw pics of a `Tuya` unit, and I want to know if my code can be uploaded to it (as any other ESP8266)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESP8285 is supported by esp8266 Arduino. You can select it in Tools menu.

[image]